Squid Proxy unable to access subdomain
I have squid proxy server sunning on centos 8 everything working fine .
Im unable to access subdomain
ksa1.aconex.com
acl localnet src 100.100.100.0/24
acl localnet src 172.30.0.0/16
acl localnet src 10.15.0.0/16

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl SSL_ports port 980      # httpd-admin (server-manager)
acl SSL_ports port 9090 # Cockpit Web UI
acl SSL_ports port 22       # SFTP
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl safe_ports port 22      # SFTP
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 980     # httpd-admin (server-manager)
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

